# Apache httpclient: get "Received fatal alert: protocol_version" sometimes

Tags: spring, apache-httpclient-4.x, tls1.2

I need help!

I run application on CentOS 6 on Tomcat 8 using Java 8.

I configure TLSv1.2 in Apache httpclient (version 4) as the following:

```
HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor httpInvokerRequestExecutor = new HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor();

SSLContext sslcontext= SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null,
            new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();

// Allow TLSv1.2 protocol, use NoopHostnameVerifier to trust self-singed cert
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext,
        new String[] { "TLSv1" , "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"  }, null, new NoopHostnameVerifier());


CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().
            setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
httpInvokerRequestExecutor.setHttpClient(httpClient);
```

I use the code above to connect to the server that may be configured with TLSv1 or TLSv1.2.

Unfortunately when the server is configured with TLSv1.2 I get sometimes the following exceptions: `Received fatal alert: protocol_version`.

It works **most** of the time but I want it will work **always**.

What is wrong?

What configuration I missed?

Is it load issue?

**Added**

What we discover during our test that in case of the exception the client start negotiation with TLSv1 and not use TLSv1.2.

What is wrong in our configuration?

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[?:1.8.0_71]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executeHttpPost(HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:312) ~[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doExecuteRequest(HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:230) ~[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executeRequest(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:138) ~[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:194) ~[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:176) ~[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:144) ~[spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
        ... 27 more
```

Comment: Change `new String[] { "TLSv1" , "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"  }` to `new String[] { "TLSv1.2"  }` ?

Comment: Thanks, but we need that it will support both servers with  `TLSv1` and `TLSv1.2`.
Why the client start to use `TLSv1` and not the highest configuration `TLSv1.2`?
Is it means we should load the TLS version from the configuration?

Comment: What Httpclient version are you using?  Have you tried out with the last version 4.5.2 if this happens?

Comment: I saw your exception,  it's 4.4.1, that's an old one released on Jan15 please try 4.5.2

Comment: So, is it bug of Httpclient?

Comment: check this https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https

Comment: Have you tried the new one?

Comment: No, since it was not clear to me if it is bug of HTTP client